# $A^2$ has a fixed point implies $A$ has also a fixed point

Tags: operator-theory, banach-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $A:X\to X$ a bounded operator. Assume that $A^2$ admits a fixed point in $X$ i.e. there exists $x_0\in X$ such that $A^2x_0=x_0$. Does this mean that $A$ has also a fixed point ?

Comment: I assume you want $x\neq 0$ for this?

Comment: $0$ is a fixed point of any linear operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than $0$?  No.  Try $A = -I$.